# Postgres regular expression regexp_split_to_array

Tags: regex, postgresql

In postgresql, I need to extract 3 specific alphanumeric characters from a field for a given column and then create the year from it. So if the value of the field is `FUT,GRA,S12,1055559` or `S11,1050830,PON`, I need `S11` or `S12` and then to create `2011` or `2012`. 
The Result can remain a text field.

I have used the following to get the `S??` out: `substring(my_field from E'(S\\d\\d),')`
but creating the year seems to be more challenging. I was hoping to use `regexp_split_to_array` but it does not seem to be working very well.

Answer (score 2):

You look like you're almost there -- you just have to append the '20' to the extracted '12'/'11':

**UPDATED** (PostgreSQL has no boundary `\b` (?!)):

```
SELECT '20'||substring(my_field from E'(?:^|\\W)S(\\d\\d)(?!\\w)') ....

-- NOTE: Old version. However there's no '\b' in this regex flavour.
SELECT '20'||substring(my_field from E'\\bS(\\d\\d)\\b') ....
```

You have to double-escape backslashes. Also, the use of the brackets in the regex means that the selected substring will be '12' or '11', not including the 'S'. The `'20'||xxxx` just concatenates the two strings.

The `(?:^|\\W)` makes sure the `Sxx` is either at the start of the string, or preceded by a non-word character (like space, or comma). This prevents the `S13` in `FUT,GRAS13,S12` from being matched.

The `(?!\\w)` makes sure the `Sxx` isn't followed by another word character (ie is not part of a larger word). This prevents `S13` being matched in `S132,GRA,S12`.

(Note - I previously had `\b` which means "word boundary" but PostgreSQL regex doesn't support that, so the `(?:^|\W)` and `(?!\w)` are ways to simulate that.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no word boundary in PostgreSQL's regex, \b means backspace.

Comment: that's right, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-LIMITS-COMPATIBILITY

Comment: ahh, that's a shame. and lookahead is supported but not lookbehind -- will update the answer. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no `word boundary` in PostgreSQL's regex, `\b` means backspace.

I would do:

```
SELECT '20'||substring('FUT,GRA,S12,1055559' from E'\\WS(\\d{2})\\W')
```

where `\W` means: not a word character.